# Excel: How to find closest number in table, many times

Tags: excel, floating-point, integer, matching, closest

### Excel

Need to find nearest float in a table, for each integer 0..99

https://www.excel-easy.com/examples/closest-match.html explains a great technique for finding the CLOSEST number from an array to a constant cell.

I need to perform this for many values (specifically, find nearest to a vertical list of integers 0..99 from within a list of floats).

Array formulas don't allow the compare-to value (integers) to change as we move down the list of integers, it treats it like a constant location.

I tried Tables, referring to the integers (works) but the formula from the above web site requires an Array operation (F2, control shift Enter), which are not permitted in Tables.  Correction:  You can enter the formula, control-enter the array function for one cell, copy the formulas, then insert table.  Don't change the search cell reference!

**Update**:

- I can still use array operations, but I manually have to copy the desired function into each 100 target cells.  No biggie.
- Fixed typo in formula.  See end of question for details about "perfection".

### Example code:

```
AI4=some integer
AJ4=MATCH(MIN(ABS(Table[float_column]-AI4)), ABS(Table[float_column]-AI4), 0)
```

repeat for subsequent integers in AI5...AI103

### Example data:

```
0.1  <= matches 0
0.5
0.95 <= matches 1
1.51 <= matches 2
2.89
```

Consider the case where target=5, and 4.5, 5.5 exist in the list.  One gives -0.5 and the other +0.5.  Searching for ABS(-.5) will give the first one. Either one is decent, unless your data is *non-monotonic*.

This still needs a better solution.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I had another problem, which pushed to a better solution.

Specifically, since the Y values for the X that I am interested in can be at varying distances in X, I will interpolate X between the X point before and after.  Ie search for less than or equal, also greater than or equal, interpolate the desired X, then interpolate the Y values.

I could go a step further and interpolate N - 1 to N + 1, which will give cleaner results for noisy data.

Comment: After re-reading this, it's really not that clear, sorry.  I should have given a bit more detail in the answer.